# The name "CartesianChart" does not exist in the namespace "using:LiveCharts.Uwp"

Tags: uwp, livecharts

I am trying to use the LiveCharts library in a UWP app. I installed LiveCharts and LiveCharts.Uwp through NuGet. I followed the steps provided on LiveCharts website, to recreate their first example, but I always get the following errors in the XAML file:

- The name "CartesianChart" does not exist in the namespace "using:LiveCharts.Uwp"
- The property 'Series' was not found in type 'CartesianChart'.

(See the attached two figures).

[XAML code and Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCAdc.png)

[C# code and Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHAbv.png)

Below are the codes of my MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="LC2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LC2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:lvc="using:LiveCharts.Uwp"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Uwp;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace LC2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { 3, 5, 7, 4 }
                },
                new BarSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<decimal> { 5, 6, 2, 7 }
                }
            };
        }
        public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this issue. I use Visual Studio 2017 and use this command line:"PM> Install-Package LiveCharts.Uwp". Looks like you haven't successfully add the reference LiveCharts.UWP. Try clear your Nuget cache and install the package again. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/856751dc-8331-4076-bf31-ba0563f0125d/uwp-some-packages-are-not-compatible-with-uapversionv100?forum=wpdevelop) is the reference about how to clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning your project?
Right click on the Solution -> Clean Solution.

If it doesn't work, I would also try once deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders manually.